# How to find the desired output using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table `tst1` which contains 3 rows (as shown below)

```
create table tst1
(
    agents varchar(5),
    trig varchar(5),
    trig2 varchar(5)
)
```

and has the data below

[image]

Now I want output like this (find the distinct trig for each agent with counts of (trig1, trig2) column combined

```
t1->3
t2->2 
t3->5
```

I have show which column to pick for A gent in below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT trig,COUNT(trig)
FROM (
    SELECT trig
    FROM tst1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT trig2
    FROM tst1 
)t1
WHERE trig IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY trig
```

or using `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES`

```
SELECT v.trig,count(v.trig)
FROM tst1 t1 
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(t1.trig),(t1.trig2)) v
WHERE v.trig IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY v.trig
```